# ckeditor doesnt show anything in the edit form and the dbms doesnt even load in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I tried the ckeditor and it works fine when adding or making a new post but the problem is when I try and edit the post.

it doesn't load properly and it doesnt show anything like the code , or even a spec, it just shows the pre default ckeditor list and it doesn't even show any data coming from the database.

any help would really be great, and info would be awesome.

I have made it into a form and then rendering it so that I can just call the function like so.

This is the _form

```
<p>
 <%= f.label :text %><br>
 <%= f.cktext_area :text, :value => 'Default value', :id => 'sometext' %>
</p>
```

Now this is in my edit

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

I tried adding the raw into it like so

```
<%= raw render 'form' %>
```

or even into the _form but it doesn't seem to show properly

after tinkering and trying the usual thing the codes show it.

```
<p>
 <%= f.label :text %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :text %>
</p>
```

when I try it and add this now it shows here , but the ckeditor doesn't show properly.

Comment: Can you post the complete the form and `<%= raw render 'form' %>` is incorrect.

Comment: hi that was the complete on the  <%= render 'form' %> from the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.cktext_area :text %>
</p>
```

I hope you are calling this partial inside a **form_for**.

Comment: so the :value => 'Default value' made it really wrong , thanks for the info again!

Comment: No problem at all, happy that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update the answer,
Just remove

```
:value => 'Default value',
```